# Check if rows of a dataset are also in another dataset and extract index

Tags: python, pandas

In my problem I have two datsets that I want to compare. Here is the 2 dataframe:

```
nodeid res_time_start_s res_time_end_s
195 291 1.505362e+09 1.505362e+09
390 296 1.503123e+09 1.503123e+09
391 296 1.503145e+09 1.503145e+09
413 296 1.511742e+09 1.511742e+09
414 296 1.511742e+09 1.511742e+09
471 297 1.503145e+09 1.503145e+09
472 297 1.504822e+09 1.504822e+09
484 297 1.511742e+09 1.511742e+09
549 304 1.505470e+09 1.505470e+09
552 304 1.506010e+09 1.506010e+09





      nodeid  res_time_start_s  res_time_end_s
195      291      1.505362e+09    1.505362e+09
390      296      1.503123e+09    1.503123e+09
391      296      1.503145e+09    1.503145e+09
413      296      1.511742e+09    1.511742e+09
414      296      1.511742e+09    1.511742e+09
471      297      1.503145e+09    1.503145e+09
472      297      1.504822e+09    1.504822e+09
484      297      1.511742e+09    1.511742e+09
549      304      1.505470e+09    1.505470e+09
552      304      1.506010e+09    1.506010e+09
553      304      1.506031e+09    1.506031e+09
554      304      1.506053e+09    1.506053e+09
555      304      1.506053e+09    1.506053e+09
556      304      1.506096e+09    1.506096e+09
557      304      1.506096e+09    1.506096e+09
558      304      1.506312e+09    1.506312e+09
559      304      1.506312e+09    1.506312e+09
560      304      1.506334e+09    1.506334e+09
561      304      1.506399e+09    1.506399e+09
562      304      1.506442e+09    1.506442e+09
563      304      1.506442e+09    1.506442e+09
564      304      1.506485e+09    1.506485e+09
565      304      1.506507e+09    1.506507e+09
2059     568      1.519189e+09    1.519189e+09
2082     569      1.518131e+09    1.518131e+09
```

I would like to check if there are rows of the first dataframe in the second dataframe and, if there are, get the index of the row in the second dataframe and append it in an array.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no reproducible example in this post, neither a tried code. I would recommend you to split the problem in different parts: check if there are rows of the first dataframe in the second one, get rows of dataframe given certain conditions, get index of certain rows, and append to an array. I am pretty sure that you will find solutions to those individual issues in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for avoid remove indices:

```
a = df1.merge(df2.reset_index())['index'].tolist()
print (a)
[195, 390, 391, 413, 414, 413, 414, 471, 472, 484, 549, 552]
```